Matching list using mockk in Kotlin ignoring items order
I have a Kotlin code like this. Using Mockk for testing.
class BugRepository {
    fun fetchAll(ids: List<Long>): List<Bug> { ... some fetching code ... } 
}

Now I have BugService using that repository and I have BugServiceTest that uses code like this:
val mocks = listOf(Bug(...), Bug(...))
every { bugRepository.fetchAll(mocks.map { it.id }) } returns mocks

How could I improve that, so the order of the ids passed to fetchAll method does not matter? Is there any mockk matcher for that?

Comparing size should be good?

Could be in some cases, but I'd also like to be sure that the list contains only the ids of items in mocks (and all of them).

Alas, the up to now accepted answer is not completely correct.
Suppose you have
val mocks = listOf(Bug(1), Bug(2))

The matcher in the solution does accept every map that contains all ids  of mocks, but it is not at all a problem if there are even some more elements. That means, that the every clause is matched for listOf(1, 2) and listOf(2, 1), as it should, but also for for listOf(1, 2, 3).
If you can be sure that there are no duplicates in mocks and the supplied list in the test, the matcher can simply be improved using equality of sets:
every {
    bugRepository.fetchAll(
        match { list -> list.toSet() == mocks.map { it.id }.toSet() }
    )
} returns mocks

But this will not work, if there are any duplicates, e.g. listOf(Bug(1), Bug(1)) will be regarded equal to listOf(Bug(1)).
If you want to take into account also the existence of duplicates, that can be done with a custom matching function that groups all duplicates and compares these in the two lists:
    fun <T> List<T>.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(list: List<T>): Boolean {
        val duplicates = groupBy { it }
        val listDuplicates = list.groupBy { it }
        return duplicates.size == listDuplicates.size &&
                duplicates.all { listDuplicates[it.key] == it.value }
    }

Then you can use this inside your every clause:
every {
    bugRepository.fetchAll(
        match { list -> list.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(mocks.map { it.id }) }
    )
} returns mocks


That's a good point, you are right! Thanks, I'm marking your answer as accepted :) Maybe we could simply use .sorted() for checking duplicates in this case (comparing lists of longs)?

As usual, I found an answer shortly after posting the question ...
Key is that no special matcher is needed, I needed to use custom matcher like this:
every { 
    bugRepository.fetchAll(
         match { list -> list.containsAll(mocks.map { it.id }) }
    ) 
} returns mocks


This matches also lists with additional items and does not take duplicates into account. It should not be used, because it can lead to buggy tests. Use solution by @Karsten Gabriel which is better.
